# WebAPI and ILMerge (aka self-hosted single exe)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, self-hosting, ilmerge

I try to build a single-executable self-hosted application with Web API.
I started using OWIN and katana, but were not able to merge them in the end.
So I made a very tiny sample project without OWIN and katana, Web API only.

In my output folder I get these files:

- Newtonsoft.Json.dll
- System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll
- System.Web.Http.dll
- System.Web.Http.SelfHost.dll

and of course the console app itself, in this case:

- WebAPI_self_hosted.exe

If I copy all 5 files to a different machinge, everything works fine.

When I try to ILMerge them, I get the following error:

```
ILMerge.Merge: ERROR!!: Duplicate type 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions' found in
assembly 'System.Web.Http.SelfHost'. Do you want to use the /alllowDup option?
at ILMerging.ILMerge.MergeInAssembly(AssemblyNode a, Boolean makeNonPublic, Boolean targetAssemblyIsComVisible)
at ILMerging.ILMerge.Merge()
at ILMerging.ILMerge.Main(String[] args)
```

Please excuse me, if this question is not really up to stackoverflow standards, but I tried a lot the last two days (even ilrepack) and right now, I am thankful for every hint :-)

See also this post with projects attached:
[Error 2 The type <T> exists in both... with ILMerge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29806751/error-2-the-type-t-exists-in-both-with-ilmerge?noredirect=1#comment47743685_29806751)

Comment: There are duplicate types so you need to configure ILMerge to properly handle them, such as using /allowDup option. The error message says it all.

Comment: Hei Li! :-)
Thanks for the answer (although it's a comment, so I can't mark it at the answer). It really was the /allowDup. There were also other parameters in the commandline but it works great with the /allowDup as the only parameter.
Now I just have to figure out how to use it with the ILMerge Task :-)

Comment: I copied it to an answer. You might accept it to help others locate the proper info.

Comment: it was a pleasure :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are duplicate types so you need to configure ILMerge to properly handle them, such as using /allowDup option. The error message says it all.

Comment: I use MSBuild.ILMerge.Task to avoid command line, and I can't find how use allowDup option. Could you tell me how ?

Comment: @Julian50 that's an open source project so contact its developers.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: This is not an original answer

For those of you using the MSBuild ILMerge task (https://ilmergemsbuild.codeplex.com/), to ignore duplicate types, the ILMerge.props file should have the value as "*" (to ignore ALL types)

```
<ILMergeAllowDuplicateType>*</ILMergeAllowDuplicateType>
```

Source:
[MSBuild.ILMerge.Task not allowing Duplicate Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44044499/msbuild-ilmerge-task-not-allowing-duplicate-types)