# The type exists in both DLLs

Tags: .net, dll, nuget, aforge, accord.net

I wanted to use something from Accord library as well as the AForge library. But when I installed it, I started getting the following error:

```
Error CS0433
The type 'IntPoint' exists in both
    'AForge, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c1db6ff4eaa06aeb' and
    'Accord, Version=3.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fa1a88e29555ccf7'
```

On this line of code:

```
startingPoint = new IntPoint(point.X, point.Y);
```

How can I ensure that I only use the original AForge DLL for this? Is there perhaps a workaround?

I tried

```
AForge.IntPoint
```

but as it turns out, Accord uses the same namespace...!

Comment: Looks like Accord.Net copied the AForge source code instead of using a reference.  Sloppy.  So you need to remove the AForge reference from your project, ought to be simpler than battling *extern alias*.

Comment: @HansPassant Unfortunately, I need stuff from `AForge.Imaging`, which relies upon `AForge`. As soon as I remove the reference to `AForge`, it still tells me I need to add a reference to `AForge`.

Comment: Just as a clarification: Accord.NET did not sloppily copy the AForge.NET source code instead of using a reference, it _effectively replaced AForge.NET because AForge.NET had been discontinued_. For a while Accord.NET was offering the same content as AForge with the same namespace so it could behave as a drop-in replacement for existing projects.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Open up your project's `References`, right-click on the offender, and select Properties.

[image]

Change your Aliases to a custom name:

[image]

Then whenever you wish to use your offending reference in your code, simply insert this at the top of your file:

```
extern alias MyAlias;
```

Comment: All code from *AForge.Imaging* has been fully included in *Accord.Imaging* starting from Accord 3.0, so there should be no need for you to reference *AForge.Imaging*.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by checking `Delete all existing files prior to publish`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me :

1- delete the reference mentioned in the error message. (although it shows a correct version, just delete it).

[image]

2- delete the related line from **packages.config**

```
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="4.2.2" targetFramework="net48" />
```

3- Reinstall the package from Nuget or reference its dll.

4- Make sure it maps the old versions to the new version in web.config

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.2.0" newVersion="4.2.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

It was correct in there but sometimes it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Properties of your Reference.
Make sure that "Specific Version" value is set to "true"